# Using @JsonAlias to Convert into Pojo Using @RequestBody

Tags: java, json

I have JSON schema as given below,

```
{
    "prty_id": "hgh",
    "customer_id": "ghjghjghj"
}
```

I have model class as given below

```
public class PARTY   {
    @JsonAlias({"prty_id", "prtyId"})
    String prtyId;

    @JsonAlias({"customer_id", "customerId"})
    String customerId;
    ......
}
```

when I am trying to deserialize using `@RequestBody` Annotation using `@RequestBody` PARTY body as method parameter I am getting null values for POJO class fields.

```
@PostMapping(value="/party/db",produces="application/json",consumes="application/json")


public Party controller(@RequestBody Party body)
//here in body parameter only i am getting null values
                {
                    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
                    String json = obj.writeValueAsString(body);
                    System.out.println("===="+json);

                    PARTY p = obj.readValue(json, PARTY.class);
                    System.out.println("------"+p);
                    p.toString();
                    return p;
                }
```

Comment: " I am not getting null values" Is this correct or should it be "I am getting null values"?

Comment: @Smile yes it should be null by mistake I wrote not null

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the getters in in your class so the jackson deseliarization can work. Also better use CamelCase in your definition:

```
public class Party {

    @JsonAlias({"prty_id", "prtyId"})
    String prtyId;

    @JsonAlias({"customer_id", "customerId"})
    String customerId;

    public String getPrtyId() {
        return prtyId;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Add controller:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Party test(@RequestBody Party body) {
    return body;
}
```

Comment: I have provided both setters and getters but then also I am getting null valus

Comment: I just checked your input json against a controller I wrote (added in the answer) and it is working well. Maybe you are not calling your controller properly

Comment: I have added the controller code.I am not getting the required output

Comment: That code is working. Please show your http request, there must be something wrong there. Have you add the Content-type header?

Comment: I am using postman to hit the url and yes have added Content-type header with value given as application/json

Comment: what do you mean by http request. I am not getting that

Comment: I mean the request you are sending to hit your controller endpoint

Comment: I am sending json data by hitting request mapping url endpoint and setting headers value.do you want me to send the url and the json data I am sending.I have tried again but of no avail. I am still getting null values

Comment: It is strange that the request hits but the field is null. So, what is the response in Postman, and what is the log in the application?

Comment: @WesterGun I am getting null values in response like this {
    "prtyId": null,
    "customerId": null}

Comment: Ah. So the real problem is, you received the request, and you have values in the DTO when you are in the controller, until you do the serialization, is that right? What is the output of `String json = obj.writeValueAsString(body);`, have you debugged? I heard that `@JsonAlias` only works for deserialization, not for serialization, so you can try adding `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: Can you repost all the classes involved in with code reformatted? I need all the details. All the lines. `PARTY` class(actually it is better renamed as  `Party` to follow Java naming convention), all the controller. All of them.

Comment: WesternGun It is working with jsonProperty.But we need to work with Jsonalias as we can provide more than one value to it. While debugging I am not getting value set in DTO only while desearlization using @request body annotation

Comment: I have provided the entire code also renamed the class to follow java convention

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `@JsonProperty` along with `@JsonAlias`. Try that.

```java
@JsonProperty
@JsonAlias(xxx, xxx)
private String xxx;
```

That is the way. At first glance the code should work.